# Render JSON and filtering by attribute in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

The following renders a json of the attribute selected_branch, including all its products, and the categories for the products:

```
render json: selected_branch, :include => { :products=> {:include =>:categories }, :enabled => true }
```

How can I only include all the products that have "Product.enabled = true"?

Answer (score 0):

Earlier in your ActiveRecord query where you presumably get the data for `selected_branch`, build it into your query before the `render :json`. I would start by using a rails scope on the model.

Something like this:

In your model (not sure what it is, so I will refer to it as Branch)

Branch.rb

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
   scope :with_enabled_products, -> { includes(:products).where(products: {enabled: true}) }
end
```

Then in your Controller

```
selected_branch = Branch.with_enabled_products
```

Then the JSON you render should be only those of the branches that have enabled products. Of course you can always tack a `.where(...)` onto the end of that scope because it is just an ActiveRecord relation and you can further narrow down your data set.

Comment: I'm getting this: NoMethodError (undefined method `enabled_products' for #<Class:0x007f92e82262d0>):

Comment: You have to call the scope, I realized in my original answer I misspelled the method call in the controller, try changing it to "Branch.with_enabled_products" instead and see how that works. I will update answer.